# How to have different body backgrounds for different pages in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have many pages as :

- page-X.php
- page-Y.php
- page-Z.php

where the above 3 pages needs to have different background-color.
The rest of the pages/posts derives its **background-color** from the **style.css** file.

I'm having trouble applying different background colors to the above 3 pages since I'm using Bootstrap 3, it leaves some margin where the gaps in the margin applies background-color from the **style.css** file. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'show_template');
function show_template() {
    global $template;
    //$custom_template = array('page-X.php', 'page-Y.php', 'page-Y.php');

    // Return the template name including custom template with extension
    $template_name = str_replace('/', '', strrchr( $template, "/" ));

    // Now you can check your page and apply the css through 
    if( $template_name == "page-X.php" ) {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the **.body** class between the **<style></style>** tags but that doesn't seem to work, what am I missing?

Comment: Does your `body` actually have a `class` of `.body`?

Comment: @mevius : yes, inside style.css I have a class as **.body**

Comment: @Sidsec9 check class through browser console.

Comment: The class existing in your CSS file doesn't mean it exists in the DOM. You need to actually view the source of the HTML web page.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a really handy [body_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function for exactly this purpose that will allow you to target the body of various pages. Here's how it would be added to your template files:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Read more in the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to apply the css on the body class. You can view the source to get the id of the page.

```
body.page-id-3938{background:red;}
```

EDIT: Another way would be to use filters to automatically add classes to these pages. and then assign classes like .red to it.

```
//Functions.php
if(is_page('X')){
add_filter( 'body_class', my_class_names($classes, 'red') );
}elseif(is_page('Y')){
add_filter( 'body_class', my_class_names($classes, 'blue') );
}elseif(is_page('Z')){
add_filter( 'body_class', my_class_names($classes, 'green') );
}
function my_class_names( $classes,$myclass ) {
    $classes[] = $myclass;
    return $classes;
}

// Styles.css file
body.red{background:red!important;}
body.blue{background:blue!important;}
body.green{background:green!important;}
```

Comment: I've been doing that, thing is I want to avoid using page-id.